# Swagger multipart-file upload JSON validation

Tags: swagger, openapi, swagger-codegen

I am not even sure if this is possible with Swagger but is it possible to validate the schema of a file we are about to upload? We are setting the schema of the application/json to which we are encoding the said file.

```
        "requestBody": {
          "required": true,
          "content": {
            "multipart/form-data": {
              "schema": {
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                  "lensData": {
                    "$ref": "#/components/schemas/Lens"
                  }
                }
              },
              "encoding": {
                "lesnData": {
                  "contentType": "application/json",
                  "explode": true
                }
              }
            },
            "application/json": {
              "schema": {
                "$ref": "#/components/schemas/Lens"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "responses": {....
```

We making use generated code through `openapi-generator-cli`. Both client and server sides.

Over here we are setting the schema type as object with lensData that is pointing to `Lens` as you can see - which from my understanding is not the same as file. Since `multipart/form-data` is usually used for file upload can the contents of the params be a file?